# Using Ruby 1.9.3 regex to pick out a list of values

Tags: ruby, regex

There exist this list:

```
 blablabla
 -c option1
 -c option2
 -c option3 
 blablablabla
 -c option4
 -c option5
 -c option6
```

How do I extract the following as blocks?

```
1)
 -c option1
 -c option2
 -c option3 

2)
 -c option4
 -c option5
 -c option6
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Is this a YAML file ?

Comment: It is not a YAML file

Comment: When you ask a question asking for code we need to see what effort you've put into answering your own question: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. See also: [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = <<_
blablabla
 -c option1
 -c option2
 -c option3 
 blablablabla
 -c option4
 -c option5
 -c option6
_

s.scan(/(?:^ -c .*#$/)+/)
# => [
  " -c option1\n -c option2\n -c option3 \n",
  " -c option4\n -c option5\n -c option6\n"
]
```

or

```
s.split(/^(?! -c ).*/).drop(1)
# => [
  " -c option1\n -c option2\n -c option3 \n",
  " -c option4\n -c option5\n -c option6\n"
]
```

Comment: In particular (?:^ -c .*#$/); the split I understand

Comment: That is an uncaptured group that starts at the beginning of a line, followed by `" -c "`, followed by zero or more non-new-line characters, followed by the new-line character.

Comment: `$/` is newline. `#` interpolates that.

Comment: I'm going to have to apologize for the longer line of questioning; what do you mean by interpolates? And why not use \n? I've never seen the $/... cant find it anywhere.

Comment: Interpolate means to evaluate that within a string, not literal `$/`. And why not use `$/`? And without you telling the OS, how am I supposed to know whether it is `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`?

Answer (score 0):

And here is the non-regexp version. A bit more typing, a bit easier to understand:

```
options = ->line{ line.strip.start_with? '-c' }

option_list = text.lines.chunk(&options)
    .select{|is_option,_| is_option}
    .map(&:last)
```